# How do I upgrade all versions of npm on my machine with NVM?

Tags: node.js, npm, nvm

NPM has [announced a security vulnerability](https://blog.npmjs.org/post/189618601100/binary-planting-with-the-npm-cli) in old versions of the `npm` CLI. I use [`nvm`](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) to manage node versions on my machine and I have many versions of node installed.

Is there an easy way to upgrade `npm` for each of them?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a little bash script that seems to do the trick:

```
nvm ls --no-colors | grep -v -E -e '.+->' | sed 's/[-*> ]//g' | while read version; do nvm exec "$version" npm i -g npm; done
```